# What does /anystring/ mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I came across this: `/sera/ === coursera`. What does `/sera/` mean? Please tell me. I do not understand the meaning of the expression above.

Comment: Short answer : it's [`Regexp.new('sera')`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]". It's really important to put in effort, then show that effort when asking. Did you read the Ruby documentation or search the internet? If not, why? If so, where and why didn't those sites help? Did you experiment with code? If not, why? If so, show us the minimum code that demonstrates the specific problem you don't understand. Without that it looks like you didn't try.

Comment: Why downvote for this?

Answer (score 3):

It's a regular expression. The more formal version of same is this:

```
coursera.match(/sera/)
```

Or:

```
/sera/.match(coursera)
```

These are both functionally similar. Either a string matches a regular expression, or a regular expression can be tested for matches against a string.

The long explanation of your original code is: *Are the characters `sera` can be found in the variable `coursera`?*

If you do this:

```
"coursera".match(/sera/)
# => #<MatchData "sera">
```

You get a MatchData result which means it matched. For more complicated expressions you can capture parts of the string using arbitrary patterns and so on. The general rule here is regular expressions in Ruby look like `/.../` or vaguely like `%r[...]` in form.

You may also see the `=~` operator used which is something Ruby inherited from Perl. It also means `match`.

Comment: You may to also say something about [Regexp#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D). AkShay, when you see something like this you can write `/sera/.class
 #=> Regexp`. When you read the doc for the class [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html) you will see that `/sera/` is a regular expression. The method `===` is being invoked on `/sera/` so `===` is an *instance method* of the class `Regexp` (or, equivalently, a method of an instance of `Regexp`, such as `/sera/`). You can then check the doc for `===` at the link for `Regexp`.